# How to reuse fetch function in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit page running, and it has you specify a sibling page `+page.ts` where you invoke the `load` method for fetching data. However, I want to paginate based on either a button or intersection observer in +page.svelte. Do I have to rewrite the function to use in the +page.svelte? Or is there a way I can use it inside of the page.ts file and just invoke it with different offsets/etc from +page.svelte? Docs don't show this specific use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With "infinite scroll"

> The original answer was for classical paging, see below.

If you want to append the new data to the existing data, making a sort of "infinite scroll" kind of setup, the first thing to do is make an api endpoint where this data can be fetched from. For example like this:

```js
// file: /api/users/[[page]]/+server.js
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
export async function GET({ params }) {
  // Get the requested page, or if not provided 0
  const page = params.page ?? 0;
  // For demo purposes
  const users = new Array(10).fill(0).map((_, index) => ({
    name: `User ${(page * 10) + index + 1}`
  }))
  // Return value
  return json(users)
};
```

Now you can call this api from your client side code to fetch more code as you would do with any other api:

```html
<!-- file: +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
    let users = data.users;
    let page = data.page;
    function loadMore() {
      fetch(`/api/users/${++page}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => (users = [...users, ...res]));
    }
</script>

<ul>
    {#each users as user}
        <li>
            {user.name}
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
<button on:click={loadMore}>Load more</button>
```

All that is left to get the first page, which can simply be done by calling the same api from your load function:

```js
// file: +page.js
function load({ url }) {
  const users = await fetch(url.origin + '/api/users').then(res => res.json());
  return {
    // initial page 0
    page: 0,
    users
  }
};
```

### With "classical" paging

> This was a previous answer from a misunderstanding of the question, but leaving it here in case someone needs it.  With this approach you use the more 'classical' way of pagination where you have urls like `posts?index=0`, `posts?index=1` or `mysite/archives/page/1`, `mysite/archives/page/2` as you see in many places.
>
> One of the benefits of this approach is that users can easily come back ("it was somewhere on page 5") or link to a specific part of the list. (with  a little extra work, replacing buttons with links, it can also be made to work **without client javascript**)

You can use searchparams with the load function, so let's say you have a url `/mysite/posts?index=0` you can configure the load function to fetch 10 posts from index 0

```js
export async function load({ url }) {
  const index = url.searchParams.get('index') ?? 0; // defaults to 0
  // other code goes here
  return {
    posts,
    index
  }
}
```

If you have that, the second part becomes trivial, just 'navigate' to the page with the next index: `

```js
goto(`/posts?index=${data.index + 1}`)
```

SvelteKit will see it's the same page, execute the matching `load` and populate `data` with the new posts (this is why I also return the index, makes it easier). While the url changes (making it easier to share) there is no **real navigation**.  You can even change the `goto` with actual links to make the entire solution work without javascript:

```html
<a href="/posts?index={data.index - 1}">Previous</a>
<a href="/posts?index={data.index + 1}">Next</a>
```

Comment: Is that the recommended use pattern for svelte? Just seems 'hacky' - Though a lot of svelte is hacky by definition.

Comment: I am sorry, but which part is hacky ?
The first section of the answer allows you to go directly to a specific page in your pagination (makes it easy to share links)
The second section uses the fact that works by simply navigating to that page
There are other ways (used in other frameworks) that are a lot hackier than that

Comment: Navigating to the page itself specifically depends on svelte choosing not to rerender. Navigating to load more data is hacky by definition. Do you disagree?

Comment: Wait, are you loading "more" data or "different" data, like in an infinite scroll vs page 1, page 2, page 3 ?

Comment: loading more data. I've never encountered a design pattern where you navigate 'away' from a page back to itself to get more data. Especially since I want to concatenate the list, and that would involve the page knowing what data existed *before* it was called. I know that Svelte 'hacks' certain JS characters and markers, so it wouldn't be out of the ordinary for this to be the best practice. At first glance though, I would like to avoid this type of pattern.

Comment: It's not really a "hack", it's more of a different way of doing pagination (both very common).  I added the "loading more data" as an alternative to my answer.